# How do I convert the contents of an unsigned char * to a const char *?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

I can across reinterpret casts, and most of the time it was brought up, a warning was given, so I am wondering if there are other alternatives (or clean implementations of reinterpret cast of course)

Comment: Unless you want to copy, `reinterpret_cast` sounds like the right solution here.

Comment: To copy? As in the contents? That is exactly what I want to do, unless I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Btw, the reason C++ doesn't allow the conversion without `reinterpret_cast` is that if `char` is signed and not 2's complement, then for negative numbers `((unsigned char)*reinterpret_cast<char*>(a)) != *a`: that is, reading the data as `char` is different from reading it as `unsigned char`. But really this rule is inherited from C, since in C++ there are problems around non-2's complement that IIRC mean `char` would need to be unsigned. And anyway, there are no non-2's complement C++ implementations, or at least none you'll ever use, so having noted this you can forget about it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say what warning was given or what the problem was, but casting to `char*` with `reinterpret_cast` should work without warnings:

```
unsigned char *a;
const char *b = reinterpret_cast<char*>(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to do.

If you just want to access the contents as `char`, then a simple
`static_cast` or using the value in a context where a `char` is expected
will do the trick.

If you need to pass the buffer to a function expecting a `char const*`,
a `reinterpret_cast` is about the only solution.

If you want a string, using the pointers into the buffer will be fine:

```
std::string
bufferToString( unsigned char const* buffer, size_t length )
{
    return std::string( buffer, buffer + length );
}
```

or you can copy into an existing string:

```
myString.assign( buffer, buffer + length );
myString.append( buffer, buffer + length );
//  etc.
```

Any string function (or algorithm, like `std::copy`) which takes two
iterators can be used.  All that is required is that dereferencing the
iterator result in a type which converts implicitly to `char`, which is
the case of `unsigned char`.

(You cannot use the string functions which take a buffer address and a
length, as these are not templates, and require the buffer address to
have type `char const*`.  And while `unsigned char` converts implicitly
to `char`, `unsigned char*` requires a `reinterpret_cast` to convert it
to `char*`.)